# Notify on policy bypass

Tags: azure-devops

I want to protect a branch in Azure DevOps with a policy. There are rare events, when we need bypass the policy. Therefore I can give the [Bypass policies permssion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#bypass-branch-policies) to some people.

Now I want to get some kind of notification, that someone bypassed the policy. Is there an way to achieve this in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the list of [Default and supported notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=vsts).
The only one related to policies that's in there is:

> Code (TFVC) - Code is checked in with a policy override

In short:
- Yes, this is possible in Azure DevOps using TFVC.
- No, this is currently not possible in Azure DevOps using Git.